# Unable to "pass data" from a UITableViewController to a UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am in troubles :)

I am unable to acheive my project because i cannot pass the data from my UITableView to a DetailView (UIViewController)

I am a beginner so i certainly do something wrong but i don't know what. I have red several tutorials and it seems to be ok ... but it's not !

Here is the .h of my UITableViewController :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "ColzaDetailViewController.h"

@interface ColzaViewController : UITableViewController <XMLParserDelegate> 

{
    XMLParser *parser;
    NSDictionary *colzaInfos;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *colzaInfos;

@end
```

I have create an NSDictionary to store the data I need to pass to the detailView (ColzaDetailViewController)

Here is the part of my UITalbeViewController .h wich is interresting for my problem :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ColzaDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ColzaDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ColzaDetail" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    colzaInfos = [parser.stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailViewController._colzaInfos = colzaInfos;

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"TEST MainView : %@", detailViewController._colzaInfos);

    detailViewController = nil;

}
```

I think everything is ok here. I have put a NSLog (TEST MainView) to check if there is something in my NSDictionary _colzaInfos.

So here are my .h and .m of my DetailVieuw (UIVIewController)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ColzaViewController.h"

@interface ColzaDetailViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UILabel *colzaSettle;
    NSDictionary *_colzaInfos;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *_colzaInfos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *colzaSettle;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ColzaDetailViewController.h"

@implementation ColzaDetailViewController

@synthesize _colzaInfos, colzaSettle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.




// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    colzaSettle = [_colzaInfos objectForKey:kCloture];

    NSLog(@"TEST DetailView : %@", _colzaInfos);
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

As you can see in the viewDidLoad, i have put a second NSLog (TEST DetailView) in order to check one more time if there is something in my Dictionary

And here are the log :

```
2012-03-14 16:23:54.240 Mobile Settles[7173:f803] TEST DetailView : (null)
2012-03-14 16:23:54.241 Mobile Settles[7173:f803] TEST MainView : {
    date = "13/03/2012\n      ";
    echeance = "Ao\U00fbt 2012\n    ";
    settle = "453.25\n      ";
    variation = "5.75";
}
```

So As you can see the log for DetailView is NULL but in the MainView contains data.

But i need to get those data in the DetailView in order to display them.

The only thing it seem "strange" for me at this step is the _colzaInfos Dictionary is not alloc and init at anytime ... But i have try to allocate it and initialize it in the .m of the detailViewController but my log was at this time

```
TEST DetailView : {}
```

Someone can help me to understand what i am doing wrong.

(if you need another part of my code to check something ... feel free to ask.)

Thanks a lot for help

---

As you told me to do, i have put the line of code at this place, please let me know if i am wrong. And as i told in the comment, When i put a breakpoint directly in this part of code and when i Run the program, the breakpoint stop the process AFTER the NSLog. And if i try to alloc/init it before, i have nothing : TEST detailView : {   }.

Sorry but it does not work :(

The code :

```
@implementation ColzaDetailViewController

@synthesize _colzaInfos, colzaSettle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        if (! _colzaInfos) 
            _colzaInfos = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `initWithNibName` method in `ColzaDetailViewController.m`.

```
if (! _colzaInfos) _colzaInfos = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

It is same issue if you're using an `NSArray`. You have to initialize the variable at some point for it to be able to hold data. You've only declared it in the `.h` file.

Comment: Hi and thanks to help. I have just tried to put the line of code you gave me a the place you told me but it not change anything. I have put a breakpoint a the place i have enter the line of code and i saw that the fonction "ViewDidLoad" is loaded first. So at the moment where the breakpoint stop the process I already have the log for the detailView print with "Null". I have try to put the line directly in the viewDidLoad but a this time it make the same thing i have already try and i have nothing ... just "TEST DetailView" : {  }. I really don't understand why it does not work :(

Comment: Maybe it is important for you to know that i am using the storyboard (and maybe i have to do something special, particulary in this case) and I have a TabBarController to "manage" several UITableViewControllers (Actually 6 ... All identique to the "ColzaViewController", only the link for the Xml change). I prefer to give you this information. It could be important